# Bash: Assign each line in file to array; if array[n] is null then replace value

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm stuck on a bash problem. The script should read each line in data.txt and assign it to an array before checking if each array value is empty. If the array value is empty, the text "unknown" should replace the empty value. Line 2 would otherwise have the text $Author.

data.txt

```
07/22/2022, 00:00:00

NASA Reveals Webb Telescope's first images of unseen universe
"We are elated to celebrate this extraordinary day with the world," said Greg Robinson, Webb program director at NASA Headquarters.
webb, telescopes, images, reveals, galaxies, star, unseen, nasa, universe, nebula, webbs, gas, view, space
```

bashscript.sh

```
# assign each line in data.txt to array
readarray data < data.txt

# for each value in array
for i in "${data[@]}"; do

    # check if value is null
    if [ -z "$data[i]" ]; then

        # if value is null, assign text "unknown" to value
        data[i]="unknown"

    fi

done


Author=${data[1]}

echo "author: $Author"
```

ouput:

```
author:
```

expected output:

```
author: unknown
```

Thanks for reading/helping....

Comment: `"${!data[@]}"` to get indexes instead of values.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks. However I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge to the code above

Comment: That would give you values of `i` that can be used as array indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your script is that a string consisting of a new-line character isn't considered a null string. The check for the empty line should have been `if [ "${data[i]}" = $'\n' ]`. Also you should have used a C-style `for` loop. Below is a corrected version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray data < data.txt

# for each value in array
for ((i = 0; i < ${#data[@]}; ++i)); do
    # check if value is null
    if [  "${data[i]}" = $'\n' ]; then

        # if value is null, assign text "unknown" to value
        data[i]="unknown"

    fi

done

Author=${data[1]}

echo "author: $Author"
```

Or, as suggested by [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984354/bash-assign-each-line-in-file-to-array-if-arrayn-is-null-then-replace-value/72984519?noredirect=1#comment128907110_72984519), use the `readarry` with the `-t` flag and check for the empty string as `[ -z "${data[i]}" ]`

Comment: Or, use `readarray -t ...` that strips off the trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, try to avoid explicit iteration over the data. Such an approach is not only slow, but also prone to errors, especially for beginners. Instead, use tools designed for the job, which will do the looping for you.

`sed 's/^$/unknown/'` puts the string `unknown` into all empty lines.

To retrieve a single line, you can use `head | tail` or `sed` again.

Your entire script can be boiled down to

```
sed -n '2{s/^$/unknown/;s/^/author: /;p;q;}' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I have restructured my code to utilise your method. However, I have not changed the accepted answer as it is more relevant to the question.